# C# Database not updated Using dataset

Tags: insert, dataset

I am trying to get data in dataset and insert 10 tables. But unable to insert data in database.
I am using below codes

```
SqlCommand cmdData = new SqlCommand("exec proc_getDataStructure", con);
SqlDataAdapter daData = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdData);
```

**proc_getDataStructure** has 10 select queries to get structure of the table
like

```
select * from tableX1 where 1=0
.
.
select * from tableX10 where 1=0
```

Get Map dataAdapter

```
daData.Fill(dsData, "INV");
```

Now I have 10 data tables in dataset 
named INV1, INV2,....,INV10

I will Rename the datatable as original table name in query

```
RenameData(ref dsData);
```

**Next Step,**
**Do Manipulation** and insert records in each dataTable of DataSET

**Do Table Mapping** for Default Adapter as in Datatables and database

```
daData.TableMappings.Add("Table", "tableX1");
.
.
.
daData.TableMappings.Add("Table1", "tableX10");
```

Try **Inserting** to database

```
new SqlCommandBuilder(daData);
dsINVStructure.AcceptChanges();
daData.Update(dsINVStructure);
```

**There is no error but and the data is not inserted to database.**

> Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you `dsINVStructure.AcceptChanges();` then there will never be anything in the dataset worth sending to the database because the dataset now thinks all the rows are `Unchanged`.

If a `datarow.RowState` is `Added` then it will be `INSERTed` by the data adapter, if it is `Modified` then it will be `UPDATEd` by the data adapter. `AcceptChanges()` converts all `Added` and `Modified` rows to `Unchanged` state, causing the adapter to ignore them